# ASP.NET MVC RegularExpression, two input length value limits

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I need simple ISBN validation, so I'm using

```
[RegularExpression("([0-9]{13})", ErrorMessage = "Invalid ISBN")]
```

and it forces user to input 13 numbers, but I would like to user can input 10 or 13 numbers, how I would need to modify code for that?

Comment: You can find lots of RegEx examples here http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=isbn&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex `^([0-9]{10}|[0-9]{13})$`